# Debugging breaks on launch with bunyan.createLogger - Node v5.8

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, bunyan

When I try to launch a node.js app using bunyan, the debugger stops once I try to create the logger. When I step through the code, I can drill into createLogger and find where it breaks.  In node_modules/bunyan/lib, the debugger detaches on line 579 -

```
assert.ok(isWritable(s.stream),
              '"stream" stream is not writable: ' + util.inspect(s.stream));
```

The debugger works until I set logger, after that it detaches and I can never step to the logger.info line.

```
import bunyan from 'bunyan'; 

const logger = bunyan.createLogger({ name: 'test' }); //debugger detaches

logger.info('Hello logger'); // debugger will NOT step to this line
```

This does not happen with winston.  I think it has something to do with winston using console and bunyan using streams.

```
import winston from 'winston';

winston.info('Simple log');

const bp = 'The debugger will stop on me';
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, but resolved it by updating to the latest version of node(5.9.1)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I'll uprooted you for the resolve but I'm holding off on marking an answer for somebody who can explain "why" it broke.  Thanks again.

Comment: i am having the same issue

Comment: and im using Visual code for debugging and Node is version is 4.2.6