# passport-azure-ad: which strategy to use

Tags: node.js, adal, azure-active-directory

We have front end developed in AngularJS and backend APIs in NodeJs. We are using Azure AD for authentication. Frontend Angular is using [adal-angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) javascript library for azure authentication. So when user comes to web site, he gets redirected to https://login.microsoftonline.com and upon successful authentication he gets redirected back to our web site. So far so good.
I have to protect backend api’s using [passport-azure-ad](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) library. Only the frontend is calling these APIs. There are two strategies available using this library
1>  OAuth2Bearer strategy
2>  OIDCStrategy for Open ID Connect

I was under impression Azure AD by default uses OpenID Connect for authentication. So I was planning to use OIDCStrategy to protect Node web api as [discussed here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect/)
However in fiddler I see the following request client (i.e angular frontend) is making when it invokes web API

```
GET http://localhost:4030/api/getemployees HTTP/1.1  
Host: localhost:4030  
Connection: keep-alive  
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36  
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOi………………………  
Referer: http://localhost:4030/  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch  
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Note Authorization tag starts with **“Bearer“** so I am assuming client is sending Bearer token to the server.

Q
1>which strategy I should be using here?
2>when should we use one over the other?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I maintain `passport-azure-ad`. The difference here is between "authorization" and "authentication".

***OAuth2*** is used for authorization (do I have access to this?).

***OpenID Connect*** is used for authentication (this is who I am).

When you are connecting to web APIs, the user most likely already has an identity (they've been through **authentication**) and now you just want to ensure that the user has access to the APIs (**authorization**). OAuth2 is used to protect resources and consumes tokens from an IdP to ensure tokens are valid and that the user has access to that resource. Bearer is just the type of token that we (and the industry) use for OAuth2. If someone comes to you without a token at all, you reject them and then it's up to the client that called you to know where to take them to get the right token you need.

OpenID Connect is built on top of OAuth2 and is purely for logging people in and getting the tokens that you will then eventually send to a Web API (which would in turn use OAuth2 with Bearer token). So OpenID Connect is used for **authentication**.

In your scenario you are using Angular which is doing the OpenID Connect authentication for you, ***so your Web APIs should be using The Bearer strategy.***

I have written a sample that walks you through all of this here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-nodejs/ that uses the MEAN stack, and which uses an iOS sample application I wrote as a front end. Playing with both of these, it's easy to see how one acts as the authentication piece (iOS app) and the other sits there and protects the API acting as the authorization piece (the node.js app)

Code for node.js app: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapi

Code for iOS app: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios

Deeper dive in to these topics is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: That really helped choosing strategy to use. However "passport-azure-ad" is using bunyan. I am using Visual Code for development & debugging. My application just stop from starting up when i run via Visual Code and the issue was 'bunyan'  and someone already posted issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089897/debugging-breaks-on-launch-with-bunyan-createlogger-node-v5-8 (is there any workaround  without updating node.js version?  I am using node version 4.2.6)

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you vote as answer then? As far as workaround, you can easily delete the logger from the app.js file and that should make it go away. Interesting about 4.2.6 and streams.

Comment: Thanks!!. There is no app.js file in "passport-azure-ad" node module. There is oidcsetup.js file which is creating the logger instance. but if i remove the variable "log" then module will fail wherever module is using log.info() method. Note that my application does not use bunyan so i dont have any reference in my application. Which app.js file you mentioned?

Comment: @BrandonWerner I want to get an JWT id_token and access_token from Azure. The JWT I plan to set in a cookie for the website to then use as a bearer for my rest api. I plan to store the access/refresh server side. Am I correct that I need to specify "code id_token" in the response_type for the OIDCStrategy? Furthermore, how do I get the JWT out of that strategy to then use with the OAuth2Bearer strategy on the REST api routes?

Comment: @ProdigousRanger do you think you could ask that as a separate question for me? That way it can be more useful for others!

Comment: @ProdigousRanger did you ever post the question for Brandon on SO?  I have that same question but don't seem to find it asked anywhere.

Comment: @RHarris I did not post another question. Sorry for the late response. I ended up using a SPA app to get, validate, and store the identity token client side. Then that token is validated on each request to my own REST API using the Bearerstrategy. Turns out so far my application does not need an access_token because I don't need special permissions. If that code would be helpful I can provide some of it in a new question.

Comment: @ProdigousRanger that would really be helpful if you could add a code snippet somewhere that shows how to use do what was Brandon described above.

Comment: @BrandonWerner Your sample and code for nodejs is not complete. There is notclientid in the creds, there is no example of where to put the "key" that you tell us to create and "copy down somewhere".  There is nothing in the portal labeled "tenant id" but using the "directory id" seems to work.