# passport-azure-ad, validation of tokens

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth-2.0, passport-azure-ad

This question is related to
[passport-azure-ad, does it parse & validate token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724793/passport-azure-ad-does-it-parse-validate-token/36851045#36851045)

I've tried to master using the passport-azure-ad module. I successfully log in my user with OpenID Connect, pick up the access_token and use it directly my REST API's which are secured by `app.get('myapi',passport.authenticate('oath-bearer', 
{failureRedirect: '/'}), 
function(req,res){});`

However, if i try to log out from the session created by OpenID connect, the token is still valid untill it expires (typically 3600 seconds).

I'm using the access_token to secure my endpoint not hosted behind a API Gateway at Microsoft, so i guess revocation of the access_token is not straight forward.

Is there any way i can check if the access_token is revoked using passport-azure-ad ? What is the best practise?

Answer (score 1):

According the description on Azure Document:

> **While directing the user to the `end_session_endpoint` will clear some of the user's single sign-on state with Azure AD B2C,** it will not sign the user out of the user's social identity provider (IDP) session. If the user selects the same IDP during a subsequent sign-in, they will be reauthenticated, without entering their credentials. If a user wants to sign out of your B2C application, it does not necessarily mean they want to sign out of their Facebook account entirely. However, in the case of local accounts, the user's session will be ended properly.

So you can directly use the `end_session_endpoint`. You can find it in the metadata document for the `b2c_1_sign_in` policy endpoint, e.g.:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=b2c_1_sign_in

As if you are using a common Azure AD application in v1, you also can find the `end_session_endpoint` in the metadata document at, e.g.:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

You can refer to [Azure Active Directory B2C: Web sign-in with OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request) for more info.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.